# Compare column (type char) use host variable in where clause using proc

Tags: c, database, oracle

I am using Oracle Pro*C.
`sys_dt` is type char(16) in the table, with values like '2016011113243456'.

```
char sysdt[24];
void get_log();
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    connect();
    while( i < 5){
        get_log(); 
        i++;
    }        
}
void get_log(){
    EXEC SQL SELECT *from mylog where sys_dt > :sysdt and rownum <=10 oder by sys_dt;
    EXEC SQL SELECT max(sys_dt) INTO :sysdt where rownum <=10;
}
```

I hope this will select 50 rows totally,10 rows every time,every time store the current max sys_dt into the globle variable sysdt, so next time it will continue from the max sysdt

I want select 10 rows every time use the condition `sys_dt > :sysdt`
but in WHERE clause `sys_dt > :sysdt` didn't work!
I can run `select * from mylog where sys_dt > '2016011113243456' and rownum <=10` using a constant string, but I really want to use a host variable.

Answer (score 1):

That is like this, isn't it?

```
#include <sqlca.h>

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char any[16+1];
    char sysdt[16+1];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

int main(){
    // here is connect()
    strcpy(sysdt, "0");
    memset(any, 0x00, sizeof(any));

    EXEC SQL SELECT sys_dt INTO :any from mylog 
        where sys_dt > :sysdt and rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: can't select into host varible more than one time?when select into a varible second time the varible will not change?

Comment: I think the declare section is the key piece of this answer.

Comment: @Hhdzhu: your code didn't show any looping; if you need to change the question, do so by editing the question, but without invalidating this answer (leave most of what you've got there at the moment in the question, and mainly add material).

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler mine version of pro*c don't need declare section for host variable

Comment: I got it.In the case of "char sysdt[24] = {0};", sysdt is null.I guess that is "where sys_dt > NULL".

Comment: char sysdt[24]; aslo not work

Comment: In the case of comparing null value, I think oracle query returns empty result set.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/comparison-operators.html